# Styling React Bootstrap Dropdown button div

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a react bootstrap single button dropdown.  I am trying to add margin space between the dropdown button and another element I have on the screen

It seems like whenever I add a className to the DropdownButton to add margin-bottom, it only applies to the button part of the DropdownButton, not the whole div of the DropdownButton.  I want to place the margin on the whole div.

```
<DropdownButton className='logOutUsersButton' title="Log Out Users" id={`dropdown-basic-1`}>
                    <MenuItem eventKey="1">All Users</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem eventKey="2">Selected Users</MenuItem>
</DropdownButton>
```

The styling for the logOutUsersButton class is as follows:

```
.logOutUsersButton{
   margin-bottom: 20%;
}
```

This causes space between the button and menu (which are both part of the dropdown).  I want the whole dropdown to use the margin-bottom, not just the button

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: tried to had a hard time setting it up for react.  I will try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping DropdownButton Component inside another div with margin-bottom can do the trick.

```
<div className='logOutUsersButton'>
<DropdownButton title="Log Out Users" id={`dropdown-basic-1`}>
                    <MenuItem eventKey="1">All Users</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem eventKey="2">Selected Users</MenuItem>
</DropdownButton>
</div>
```